# add a hook of Woocommerce to a plugin but it only shows and doesn't function properly

Tags: plugins, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I have this plugin for my site that can verify OTP. It shows and works perfectly on the registration page.

I wanted to add the exact same field to my checkout register. I've added the hook of Woocommerce checkout place. It shows and fits perfectly, but it doesn't work when I try to check the button. I've tested it and it doesn't send the OTP. In other words, it's just a field that verifying that does not function as it does on the register page. picture one is how it should work after I verify.

[image]

The second picture is on the checkout page that only appears but doesn't do anything:

[image]

Can someone kindly point out what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}


class Xoo_Ml_Phone_Frontend{

    protected static $_instance = null;
    public $settings;

    public static function get_instance(){
        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function __construct(){
        $this->settings = xoo_ml_helper()->get_phone_option();
        $this->hooks();
    }

    public function hooks(){

        if( $this->settings['r-default-country-code-type'] === 'geolocation' ){
            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'fetch_geolocation' ), 0 );
        }


        if( $this->settings['l-enable-login-with-otp'] === "yes" ){
            add_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end', array( $this, 'wc_login_with_otp_form' ) );
            add_filter( 'gettext', array( $this, 'wc_login_username_field_i8n' ), 999, 3 );
        }

        if( $this->settings['r-enable-phone'] === "yes" ){
            add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', array( $this, 'wc_register_phone_input' ) );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start', array( $this, 'wc_myaccount_edit_phone_input' ) );
        }


        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' ,array( $this,'enqueue_styles' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , array( $this,'enqueue_scripts' ), 0 );
        
    }


    public function fetch_geolocation(){
        Xoo_Ml_Geolocation::get_data();
    }



    public function wc_login_with_otp_form(){
        $args = self::wc_register_phone_input_args( array(
            'cc_show' => $this->settings['l-enable-cc-field']
        ) );
        $args = apply_filters( 'xoo_ml_wc_otp_login_form', $args );
        return xoo_ml_get_login_with_otp_form( $args );

    }


    //Enqueue stylesheets
    public function enqueue_styles(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );

        if( !wp_style_is( 'select2' ) ){
            wp_enqueue_style( 'select2', "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" );
        }

        wp_enqueue_style( 'xoo-ml-style', XOO_ML_URL.'/assets/css/xoo-ml-style.css', array(), XOO_ML_VERSION );
        $style = '';
        if( $this->settings[ 'l-login-display' ] === "yes" ){
            $style = "
                .xoo-el-form-login{
                    display: none;
                }
            ";
        }
        wp_add_inline_style('xoo-ml-style', $style );
    }

    //Enqueue javascript
    public function enqueue_scripts(){

        if( !wp_script_is( 'select2' ) ){
            wp_enqueue_script( 'select2', "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js", array('jquery'), XOO_ML_VERSION, true ); // Main JS
        }


        if( xoo_ml_helper()->get_phone_option('m-operator') === 'firebase' ){
            wp_enqueue_script( 'firebase', 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.0/firebase-app.js', array(), false, true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'firebase-auth', 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.0/firebase-auth.js', array(), false, true );
        }


        wp_enqueue_script( 'xoo-ml-phone-js', XOO_ML_URL.'/assets/js/xoo-ml-phone-js.js', array('jquery'), XOO_ML_VERSION, true ); // Main JS

        $settings = $this->settings;

        wp_localize_script('xoo-ml-phone-js','xoo_ml_phone_localize',array(
            'adminurl'              => admin_url().'admin-ajax.php',
            'resend_wait'           => $settings['otp-resend-wait'],
            'phone_form_classes'    => json_encode( self::phone_form_classes() ),
            'auto_submit_reg'       => $settings['r-auto-submit'],
            'show_phone'            => $settings['r-phone-field'],
            'otp_form_type'         => $settings['m-otp-form-type'],
            'operator'              => $settings['m-operator'],
            'inline_otp_verify_btn' => apply_filters( 'xoo_ml_inline_otp_verify', '<span class="xoo-ml-inline-verify">'.__( 'Verify', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' ).'</span>' ),
            'strings'               => array(
                'verified'              => __( '<span class="dashicons dashicons-yes"></span>', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' ),
                'verify'                => __( 'Verify', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' ),
                'placeholderInlineOTP'  => __( 'Enter OTP', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' )
            ),
            'notices'               => array(
                'empty_phone'   => xoo_ml_add_notice( __( 'Please enter a phone number', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' ), 'error' ),
                'empty_email'   => xoo_ml_add_notice( __( 'Email address cannot be empty.', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' ), 'error' ),
                'empty_password'=> xoo_ml_add_notice( __( 'Please enter a password.', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' ), 'error' ),
                'invalid_phone' => xoo_ml_add_notice( __( 'Please enter a valid phone number without any special characters & country code.', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' ), 'error' ),
                'try_later'     => xoo_ml_add_notice( __( 'Something went wrong. Please try later', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' ), 'error' ),
                'verify_error'  => xoo_ml_add_notice( __( 'Please verify your mobile number', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' ), 'error' ),
                'error_placeholder' => xoo_ml_add_notice( '%s', 'error' ),
                'success_placeholder' => xoo_ml_add_notice( '%s', 'success' ),
                'firebase_api_error' => xoo_ml_add_notice( __( 'Firebase API key is empty. Please setup firebase keys, read documentation.', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' ), 'error' ),
            ),
            'login_first'   => $settings['l-login-display'],
            'html'          => array(
                'otp_form_inline'   => xoo_ml_helper()->get_template( "xoo-ml-inline-otp-input.php", array(), '', true ),
                'otp_form_external' => xoo_ml_helper()->get_template( "xoo-ml-external-otp-form.php", array(), '', true ),
            ),
            'firebase'  => array(
                'api'       => xoo_ml_helper()->get_service_option('fb-api-key'),
            )
        ));


        if( $settings['m-operator'] === 'firebase' && xoo_ml_helper()->get_service_option('fb-config') ){
            wp_add_inline_script('xoo-ml-phone-js', 'xoo_ml_phone_localize.firebase.config = '. htmlspecialchars_decode( xoo_ml_helper()->get_service_option('fb-config') ) );
        }

    }


    public static function wc_register_phone_input_args( $args = array() ){
        $default_args = array(
            'label'         => __('Phone', 'mobile-login-woocommerce'),
            'cont_class'    => array(
                'woocommerce-form-row',
                'woocommerce-form-row--wide',
                'form-row form-row-wide'
            ),
            'input_class'   => array(
                'woocommerce-Input',
                'input-text',
                'woocommerce-Input--text'
            )
        );
        return wp_parse_args( $args, $default_args );
    }

    public function wc_myaccount_edit_phone_input(){
        return xoo_ml_get_phone_input_field( self::wc_register_phone_input_args(
            array(
                'form_type'     => 'update_user',
                'default_phone' => xoo_ml_get_user_phone( get_current_user_id(), 'number' ),
                'default_cc'    => xoo_ml_get_user_phone( get_current_user_id(), 'code' ),
            )
        ) );
    }

    public function wc_register_phone_input(){
        return xoo_ml_get_phone_input_field( self::wc_register_phone_input_args() );
    }


    public static function phone_form_classes(){
        return apply_filters( 'xoo_ml_phone_form_classes', array(
            'woocommerce-form-register'
        ) );
    }


    public function wc_login_username_field_i8n( $translation, $text, $domain ){

        if( $domain === 'woocommerce' && ( strcmp( $text, 'Username or email' ) === 0 || strcmp( $text, 'Username or email address' ) === 0 ) ){
            return __( 'Phone or Email address', 'mobile-login-woocommerce' );
        }
        return $translation;
    }

}

function xoo_ml_phone_frontend(){
    return Xoo_Ml_Phone_Frontend::get_instance();
}
xoo_ml_phone_frontend();
```

And this is what I added that doesn't work properly check the 2nd picture it has no function verify does not do anything:

```
    if( $this->settings['r-enable-phone'] === "yes" ){
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_registration_form', array( $this, 'wc_register_phone_input' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', array( $this, 'wc_register_phone_input' ) ); 
        add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start', array( $this, 'wc_myaccount_edit_phone_input' ) );
                                             
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to look for a hook or filter that handles checkout form validation. At the moment you're only hooking registration actions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. as hook goes I've searched the PHP nothing else. can you please look at the code again I've edited and update it with filters